# Flash BIOS before Lubuntu 12.10 install on Asus Eee PC 1015BX

Tags: lubuntu, asus, bios

I would like to install Lubuntu 12.10 on an Asus Eee PC Seashell 1015BX, but have noticed that there are a number of BIOS updates on the Asus support page. Does anyone have any experience updating an Asus PC BIOS before installing Ubuntu (Lubuntu)? The laptop currently has Windows 7 Starter installed.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is if it isn't broke, don't fix it. Is there a feature that one of the BIOS updates offers that you expect to rely on? If not, don't bother. If you still feel that you should update your BIOS, generally there are a few ways of going about it. Sometimes there's a windows installer and you just run an executable that does the trick. I went to Asus's download page and all they offer is a zipped `.rom` file. That means you'll have to do it manually. I don't know the features available on your BIOS and your EEE PC probably doesn't have a disc drive, so I recommend using the Ultimate Boot CD (if you want to save the disc, you could even boot UBCD off a pen drive). Here's a forum thread that should help you [on the UBCD site](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=2863). Last time I flashed a BIOS was on a Pentium 4 with a CD, looks like in your case you're going to have to deal with the command prompt in freeDOS running off the UBCD (plus if you run it off a USB key, you may be able to store the BIOS rom on the same pen drive to flash the BIOS).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just checked the BIOS version compared to the updates and from what I can see, all of the important updates are older than my BIOS version. It looks like I dodged a bullet :-)